# Running multiple chains in celery in order

Tags: python, synchronization, celery

I am trying to use celery chains to check files and then record them as checked.

Currently my code looks like this

```
for file in list_of_files:
    task_chain = chain(task1.s(file), task.si(file))
    task_chain.apply_async()
```

However when I run the code the worker performs all the "task1"s before then performing "task2"s. Is there a way of telling the worker to run task2 immediately after task1?

Many thanks for any help.

Comment: Quick observation:  I see task1.s but there is no task2.s visible in the code you have provided.  Am I missing something?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried callbacks as demonstrated in the celery docs: https://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/userguide/canvas.html#callbacks

so you could try:

```
task_chain = chain(task1.s(file), task.si(file))
task_chain.apply_async(link=task2.si())
```